# Aggregating groups of date ranges

Tags: sql

Assuming a simple query such as:

**select name, role, placeOfWork, startDate, endDate from SampleTable**

which displays the name of employees, the role they've occupied at a workplace from a start date to an end date. End dates are null when the job assignment is current.

I have a resultset for such query where I get returned such sample:

```
Jack      Cook       Jimmy's Burger Joint    01-01-2010     21-01-2010
Jack      Cook       Jimmy's Burger Joint    21-01-2010     31-03-2010
Jack      Cook       Jimmy's Burger Joint    31-03-2010     24-12-2010
Ronald    Marketing  McDonald's              01-01-2010     22-01-2010
Ronald    Marketing  McDonald's              22-01-2010     06-06-2010
Ronald    Marketing  McDonald's              06-06-2010     NULL
Jack      Cosmonaut  NASA                    01-01-2011     NULL
...
```

I would like to aggregate job assignments into "single conceptual ones", e.g.:

```
Jack      Cook       Jimmy's Burger Joint    01-01-2010     24-12-2010
Ronald    Marketing  McDonald's              01-01-2010     NULL
Jack      Cosmonaut  NASA                    01-01-2011     NULL
...
```

As much as possible I would like to avoid temp tables as I need the query to run from various places. I could not work it out using either an inner join or a group by.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sybase but I am hoping this can be ANSI sql

Comment: The actual solution will vary by DBMS, but my general approach to these problems is to expand your ranges into rows, i.e. `01-01-2010 --> 05-01-2010` expands to 5 rows. Then you have a set that you can apply [gaps and islands](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf) logic to. Expanding the dates can be done by joining with a numbers table. If the next start date will always equal the previous end date then you can solve this using recursion which may be faster.

Comment: An observation: There's a gap of around 4 months in the records for Ronald. Is the output you have shown consistent with your concept of single record in that case?

Comment: Indeed, that was an issue with the example, I updated it

Comment: I actually also have such query running on Microsoft SQL Server, is there any ANSI sql that will satisfy both Sybase and MS Sql Server ?

Comment: There's still a 3 month gap? Should it still be a single row beginning on 01-01-2010? If this is the case the solution is much simpler and you can ignore my previous comment

Comment: I cannot see any dates in this table.

Comment: Strawberry, I am confused by your comment; there are dates in these tables, such literals are commonly accepted as dates in Sybase and MS Sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this with simple logic.  An assignment starts when there is no overlap with the previous assignment.  In that case, we can assign a value to each assignment which is the number of assignments in the past.  This is easiest with `lag()` and cumulative sum.  Here is a version without those:

```
with stp as (
      select name, role, placeOfWork, startDate, endDate,
             (case when exists (select 1
                                from SampleTable st2
                                where st2.name = st.name and st2.role = st.role and
                                      st2.placeOfWork = st.placeOfWork and
                                      st2.endDate = st.StartDate
                               )
                   then 0
                   else 1
              end) as PeriodStart
      from SampleTable st 
     ),
     stpg as (
      select stp.*,
             (select sum(PeriodStart)
              from stp stp2
              where stp2.name = stp.name and stp2.role = stp.role and
                    stp2.placeOfWork = stp.placeOfWOrk and
                    stp2.StartDate <= stp.StartDate
             ) as grp
      from stp
select name, role, placeOfWork, min(StartDate) as StartDate, max(endDate) as endDate
from stpg
group by grp, name, role, placeOfWork;
```

Comment: I could suspect where the st2 alias would be declared but it's not

Comment: Anyway, transformed this to work on Sybase (with keyword does not exist) and the result is very satisfying so far

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this would be to first expand out your ranges into rows (using a numbers or calendar table), so this row for example:

```
 StartDate  |   Enddate 
------------+------------
 2010-01-01 | 2010-03-01
```

Becomes

```
    Date    
------------
 2010-01-01
 2010-01-02
 2010-01-03
```

Since a lot of the date functions are DBMS specific, I am using SQL-Server specific syntax, but this should be readily adaptable to sybase (which I am not familiar with at all), this will expand a simple table of just start and end date to all the dates in the range:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartDate) AS Date
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN Numbers n
            ON  DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartDate) <= t.EndDate
```

Now you have a set than can be solved using [Gaps and Islands Logic](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf). After expanding your range you then need to identify the gaps and islands, to do this I am using DENSE_RANK which is supported in both sybase and SQL Server. This gives the column `GroupingSet` in the below. The final step is then to just aggregate based on your islands:

```
WITH Expanded AS
(   SELECT  Name,
            Job,
            Company,
            StartDate,
            DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartDate) AS Date,
            CASE WHEN EndDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EndDateIsNull
    FROM    T
            INNER JOIN Numbers n
                ON  DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartDate) <= ISNULL(t.EndDate, t.StartDate)
), Grouped AS
(   SELECT  Name,
            Job,
            Company,
            Date,
            DATEADD(DAY, -DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, Job, Company ORDER BY Date), Date) AS GroupingSet,
            EndDateIsNull
    FROM    Expanded
)
SELECT  Name, 
        Job, 
        Company,
        MIN(Date) AS StartDate, 
        CASE WHEN MAX(EndDateIsNull) = 0 THEN MAX(Date) END AS EndDate
FROM    Grouped
GROUP BY Name, Job, Company, GroupingSet
ORDER BY Name, Job, StartDate;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84c1d/3)**

Comment: +1 for the effort &  Gaps and Islands Logic:) I changed source data a little bit: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0527/1. Still can not handle the case "job in the middle of other job"

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong SQL Fiddle link initially then edited the answer, so the query in the link you have posted doesn't actually match the query in my answer. [Is this what you would expect?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03eeb/1)

Comment: this solution is good, however, I'm dealing with about 300K assignments, over a date span of about 30 years. There is a risk of overflowing the memory that this database has available to me as a user to build temp tables. +1 though, would be tempted to use this approach for smaller data sets

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT name, role, placeOfWork,
       MIN (startDate),
       CASE WHEN COUNT(endDate) = COUNT(startDate) THEN MAX(endDate) ELSE NULL END
FROM SampleTable
GROUP BY name, role, placeOfWork;
```

Comment: If there were any gaps in the assignments presented above, then they would not be display as separate extra assignments; if Sam had worked at NASA in 2010, then Burger King in 2011, then NASA again in 2012, this would show he's been at NASA from 2010 to 2012, working two jobs in 2011.